# JSXGraph drag entire circle from center point

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I'm new to JSXGraph. I am trying to construct a circle using two points where A is the center point and B sits on the circle itself. What I need is for B to resize the circle (no problem, it does this) but when A is dragged for it to move the entire circle around without resizing it.

The examples they give on the link below have both A and B resizing the circle: http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Circle

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a tricky question. The solution is to use groups. Pack the two (free) points into a group like this:

```
    var board, A, B, circ, grp;

    board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box6', 
         {boundingbox:[-5,5,5,-5], keepaspectratio:true});

    A = board.create('point',[-1, -1], {size: 5, name: 'A', color: 'blue'});
    B = board.create('point',[2, -1], {size: 5, name: 'B', color: 'red'});
    circ = board.create('circle', [A, B]);

    grp = board.create('group', [A, B]);
    grp.removeTranslationPoint(B);
```

In this case, dragging the two points results moves the circle while keeping the radius constant.

Moreover, if you want to move the circle by dragging at its center but allow to resize the circle by dragging B, point B has to be removed from the list of translation points in the group:

```
    var board, A, B, circ, grp;

    board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box6', 
         {boundingbox:[-5,5,5,-5], keepaspectratio:true});

    A = board.create('point',[-1, -1], {size: 5, name: 'A', color: 'blue'});
    B = board.create('point',[2, -1], {size: 5, name: 'B', color: 'red'});
    circ = board.create('circle', [A, B]);

    grp = board.create('group', [A, B]);
    grp.removeTranslationPoint(B);
```

Comment: Thanks, Alfred. That was the answer that got me going properly on this.